# java.sql.TimeStamp doesn't have default constructor

Tags: java, json, jersey-2.0

I'm writing my web services in Java and there's one thing where I stuck. I  want to send java.sql.TimeStamp as a json response but got the **IllegalAnnotationException**. I'm using **jersey 1.19** and below is exception.

```
javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException:
com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 1 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
java.sql.Timestamp does not have a no-arg default constructor.
this problem is related to the following location:
    at java.sql.Timestamp
    at public java.sql.Timestamp response.TransactionStatusResponse.command_receiving_datetime
    at response.TransactionStatusResponse
    at public java.util.List response.OnDemandRequestResponse.getData()
    at response.OnDemandRequestResponse
```

The following shows is my **JsonResponseModel** class.

```
@XmlRootElement
public class TransactionStatusResponse {

     public TransactionStatusResponse() {
     }  

     public String transaction_id;
     public String msn;
     public String global_device_id;
     public String type;
     public String type_parameters;
     public Timestamp command_receiving_datetime;

}
```

I also have seen the java.sql.TimeStamp class and it does not have the default constructor. So, is there any way to send no default-arg constructor object in json response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to register adapter for this

```
public class TimestampAdapter extends XmlAdapter<Date, Timestamp> {
      public Date marshal(Timestamp v) {
          return new Date(v.getTime());
      }
      public Timestamp unmarshal(Date v) {
          return new Timestamp(v.getTime());
      }
  }
```

then annotate your timestamp like

```
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter( TimestampAdapter.class)
        public Timestamp done_date;
```

and you should use java.util.Date instead of java.sql.Date